# How does Clairvoyant sight work in regards to covers?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

If someone using that form ability knows only one cover of someone and tries to find that cover  would he see the demon in question even if he has a different cover active? (one which he does not know about even).

Edit: Although technically different it is similar enough to also be handled in this question. If one knows only the full demonic form of someone and not the cover could he see that one in that cover?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience playing with Demon, when a cover isn't being currently used it's not truly in the universe. It becomes untargetable and only exists in the forms that the cover rating dictates such as documents, homes owned, etc.

I will need to get my hands on my rulebook but your question hasn't been answered for a bit so I wanted to leave you something. I believe if you have seen a demon's true form (and DEFINITELY if you know their true name), there is a contest to resist being discovered while in cover equal to the covers rating. If I can get my hands on my core book I'll be after to give you citations.